# JAXB - Should we bind classes with @XmlSeeAlso if they are fields of the same class

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

Lets have the following class:

```
@XmlType(name = "TestClass")
//@XmlSeeAlso({SomeClassOne.class, SomeClassTwo.class})
public class TestClass{

    @XmlElement
    private SomeClassOne someClassOne;

    @XmlElement
    private SomeClassTwo someClassTwo;

}
```

I try to serialize the object to XML using context and Marshaller. We have the following statement

```
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestClass.class);
```

The question is: Should I describe all binding classes of TestClass (which are SomeClassOne and SomeClassTwo) in the @XmlSeeAlso -     `@XmlSeeAlso({SomeClassOne.class, SomeClassTwo.class})`

Comment: Why you just not write unit-test and check it?

Answer (score 2):

`JAXB` will automatically bind any mapped class contained by the class used to instantiate the **JAXBContext**.

`@XmlSeeAlso` is used for binding sub-classes.

An example from [`@XmlSeeAlso`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) documentation :

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Dog.class,Cat.class})
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

This enable an `JAXBContext.newInstance(Animal.class)` to correctly bind the `Dog` and `Cat` classes, despite the fact that they are never used in the `Animal` class.

So, in your exemple, it is not necessary to use `@XmlSeeAlso` to bind the `SomeClassOne` and `SomeClassTwo` classes.